# Display GitHub Flavored Markdown into Swagger pages

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I want to create several pages using GitHub Flavored Markdown and to store them into `resources` directory into my project.

After that I would like to display the pages with the Markdown code into Swagger web pages. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure you're able to edit any html of those resources?

Comment: Yes, I am. Is there some solution?

Comment: What framework/library do you use - Springfox, JAX-RS+Swagger Core, something else?

Comment: Sounds like you already know the solution... Put html tags around your code content

Comment: @Helen I use Springfox which generates Spring Endpoints data.